# Ms Access fade subform or text box possible?

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba, fadeout

I've built a database that looks like a standalone application... Hiding main window, fade in / out forms when opening and closing...etc

Now what I was after is..is it possible to fade out a textbox when a button is pressed...I know we can use a timer to possibly emulate this but I'm looking for a smooth fade out feature for either a textbox or subform.

Many thanks
Max

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: nope.

**Longer answer**: not in VBA.

**Completely overkill work-around**: design a WPF UserControl in C# or VB.NET, make your sleek animations with XAML. Then create your WinForms UserForm, add a WPF interop container, embed your WPF UserControl in there, expose your form to COM. You'll need to also expose the *ViewModel* class and figure out a way to architect the thing so that the VBA code can interact with the .NET form - which isn't impossible. In your VBA project, reference the type library (.tlb) for your WPF UI, and instantiate the form.

The slight little issue is that you now have a .NET class library to maintain *on top* of your VBA project... and if you can make a .NET class library, you might as well make yourself a standalone application, instead of something the *looks* like one.

Answer (score 0):

A fade hack could *potentially* be achieved by putting an alpha PNG image in front of the text box and then varying the alpha.

Problem is you can't use VBA's LoadPicture with transparent PNG, so you need to use GDI+.

That said, I've definitely had transparency working on a form, but never checked the varying alpha approach, so you may find the form won't allow it.

This [article/site](http://www.mosstools.de/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=77) in German, translates well enough in Google Translate, and shows how to achieve transparency in VBA.